# swift how to hide image but still let it occupy space in stack view

Tags: ios, swift, imageview

how to hide image but still let it occupy space in stack view ?

currently i set `image.isHidden = false`, and my stack view elements rearrange and squeeze the image space away. Is there a way to have the image still occupy space while being hidden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
image.alpha = 0
```